# Is there a data source indicating how long most major surgeries take, and what are the associated risks/outcomes?

Tags: medical

I'm looking to play around with statistics around major surgery types; is there a publicly available data source I can work with which lists information such as:

types of major surgeries, together with amount of time per procedure (average, standard deviation, broken down by complication, etc...)
risk information to any level of detail
any sort of other aggregate information
Any data set would be interesting (ie, for any geographical region or legal jurisdiction - i know some of this info might be harder to collect in say the US than elsewhere)